# Let's Encrypt plesk extension creates invalid vhost config

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, lets-encrypt, plesk

I've installed the [Let's Encrypt extension](https://ext.plesk.com/packages/f6847e61-33a7-4104-8dc9-d26a0183a8dd-letsencrypt) in Plesk, which automatically renews the certificates served to Apache. But today I've received the following email which reminds me to renew my certificate:

> From: Let's Encrypt Expiry Bot 
>   Date: 2017-06-27 0:13 GMT+02:00
>   Subject: Let's Encrypt certificate expiration notice for domain "***.ch"
>   To: info@***.ch
>
> Hello,
>
> Your certificate (or certificates) for the names listed below will
>   expire in 19 days (on 16 Jul 17 18:40 +0000). Please make sure to
>   renew your certificate before then, or visitors to your website will
>   encounter errors.
>
> [...}

When I try to renew the certificate in the extension settings, I get the following error message:

```
Error: Let's Encrypt SSL certificate installation failed: Challenge marked as invalid.
Details: Fetching http://***.be/.well-known/acme-challenge/***: Error getting validation data
```

That's when the webserver stopped working and starting it again doesn't work:

```
# service apache2 start
 * Starting web server apache2
Syntax error on line 54 of /etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/vhosts/****.ch.conf:
SSLCertificateFile: file '/opt/psa/var/certificates/cert-***' does not exist or is empty
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

The configured certificate file is missing, what happened and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recreating the Apache config with Plesk fixed the path to the certificate:

```
/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/httpdmng --reconfigure-all
```